# phonegap/cordova app - how to show text on top of other activity - barcodescanner

Tags: android, cordova, webview, phonegap-plugins

I have created an cordova app for android, which uses phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner for scanning QR codes. 
I need user could continuously scan more QR codes and I need to give to user response if QR code contains correct string.
Now I have it like this: Start scanning, in callback check if QR code contains correct string, show window.alert() and start scanning again.
This approach is not ideal, because user has to click on alert after each scan. I just need to write on display, that code is OK or not.
If barcodescanner activity was not fullscreen, but embedded in div, it could be solved easily, but this plugin supports fullscreen mode only. Other commercial plugins support scanning window in part of screen, but their price is for this project unacceptable.
So, is there any way how to show short text information on screen while scanner is running?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the issue is that the barcode scanner plugin shows the barcode scanner as a separate activity. alert dialogs are shown below the barcode scanner activity and are invisible until the barcode scanner activity is closed.

You might be able to modify the barcode scanner plugin to achieve what you want. You will have to modify the Plugin's Objective-C or Java code and implement the result handling there, since there is not way to display results on top of the barcode scanner activity.

You might also consider another approach. Instead of showing an alert that the code was correct, you might also just play different sounds depending on whether a correct/incorrect code was scanned.

Or, you might be able to use the Scandit Barcode Scanner SDK Community Edition which supports QR codes. You will have to check if your app is eligible for the Community license, though.

Disclaimer: I work at Scandit as a software engineer.